# Speed up MS ACCESS VBA Script iterating over bytes in String

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need a very simple hash-function and based on some experiments with excel just a sum of byte values should do it:

```
Function HashPart(strVal As String) As Long
    ' work with byte representation for speed
    Dim b() As Byte
    b = strVal

    Dim result As Long
    result = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(b)
        result = result + b(i)
    Next
    Quersumme = result
End Function
```

This is done many time over all records (about 100) resulting from a query:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

' Loop through records
Do While Not rs.EOF
    resultHash = resultHash + HashPart(rs(0))
    resultLen = resultLen + Len(rs(0))
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
MyHash = Str(resultLen) & "-" & Str(resultHash)
```

This works well enough, but is very slow. My previous version iterating over the String using Mid was even slower, but now I am out of ideas how to improve this.

Is there a way to speed this up?

---

Edit: the problem wasn't in the hash function but in the query.

Comment: I can't see where you're quantifying `HashPart = `.

Comment: @user3819867 fixed, thanks!

Comment: How long (on average) are your strings, and how slow is "very slow"? If I run this 10,000 times on a constant string with 110 characters, it takes 0.04 seconds. So most probably your query is slow, not the function.

Comment: @Andre You are right, after indexing the right columns the speed issues are gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test code with constant strings showed that the function itself is very fast. 10,000 calls with strings of ca. 110 characters take only 0.04 seconds.

Conclusion: the performance problem was in the query, not the hash function.

```vb
Function HashPart(strVal As String) As Long

    ' work with byte representation for speed
    Dim b() As Byte
    Dim result As Long
    Dim i As Long

    b = strVal
    result = 0

    For i = 0 To UBound(b)
        result = result + b(i)
    Next

    HashPart = result

End Function

Sub TestHashPart()

    Const NumRounds = 10000

    Dim i As Long
    Dim res As Long
    Dim SumRes As Double    ' avoid limitation of Long (2^31)
    Dim S As String
    Dim t1 As Single

    t1 = Timer
    For i = 1 To NumRounds
        ' constant string with tiny variations
        S = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ " & CStr(i ^ 2)
        res = HashPart(S)
        ' This would slow down the process dramatically. DO NOT activate for NumRounds > 1000 !
        ' Debug.Print i, res, Len(S), S
        SumRes = SumRes + res
    Next i

    Debug.Print SumRes, Timer - t1 & " seconds"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! After searching in the right direction I found a way to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function HashPart(strVal As String) As Long
    ' work with byte representation for speed
    Dim b() As Byte
    b = strVal
    For i = 0 To UBound(b)
        HashPart = HashPart + b(i)
    Next
End Function
```

There's not much to improve, I think if you don't put the additional variable in there and don't set a number to 0 that defaults to 0 you're very slightly better off.